# Is this the correct way to return 204 "No Content" using Spring?

Tags: java, weblogic12c, spring-web

I'm trying to delete a resource setting http status **NO_CONTENT** using Weblogic and the response takes 30 seconds to complete. Am i misusing Spring or is there a bug in Weblogic?

I've tried this on Weblogic 12.2.1.0.0 using Spring 5.0.12. The request is completed, the resource is removed but the client waits for 30 seconds (browser TTFB) after that. This seems to be a kind of timeout.

As a workaround, we could return http status **OK**.

```java
@DeleteMapping(value = "/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<Void> delete(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
    useCase.remove(id);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
}
```

I expected the client to immediately receive the response, but it waits 30 seconds.

Comment: It also takes 30s when you return OK instead?

Comment: A more fluent way of returning a 404 is  `return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();` . But what you're doing is correct, in terms of getting a 404 response.

Comment: @jhamon No. When i return OK, it responds immediately.

Comment: Can you show response headers that you get on both 200 and 204 responses? Did you use `@RequestMapping` with `produces` on `@Controller` level to force default response body format?

Comment: Ugh, I meant 204 above, and now it's too late to edit my comment.  But the `.noContent()` _is_ the correct method to call to get the right `ResponseEntity`.

Comment: @Karol Dowbecki. I used @RequestMapping without produces.

Response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 15 Apr 2019 17:25:03 GMT
Server: Apache
Content-Length: 0
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=80
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

```
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Date: Mon, 15 Apr 2019 18:26:31 GMT
Server: Apache
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=80
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Comment: @Jordan I liked the fluent way and i'll modify the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Comparing to 200 response your 204 response has no [`Content-Length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Length) header. Try adding it manually to see if it helps with your application server handling empty response body:

```
return ResponseEntity.noContent().header("Content-Length", "0").build();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `@ResponseStatus` annotation.

```
@DeleteMapping(value = "/{id}")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
public ResponseEntity<Void> delete(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug from OHS.
https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Middleware/2162306_1.html

The bug behavior is: the plugin keeps waiting for the content body, and 204 doesn't have a body finally it triggers a read timeout (this is the 30+ secs).

You need to download the patch and apply to OHS, or change the HTTP code as *workaround*, perhaps a 202 (accepted).

Comment: Thanks! I'll show this to the infraestructure team.

Comment: This patch applies to version 12.1.3.0.0 and later. 12.2.1.0.0 is the current version. 
So this patch has already been applied. We checked this out. Maybe the apache server is doing the same.